# Value from views.py, not getting reflected in HTML page : Django

Tags: django, render

i got a problem while passing element from views.py to html page , first i will explain about UI , i have a single html page with name .

```
side-menu-light-tabulator.html
```

and UIlooks something like this
[image: UI1]

and when i click on show server list , it will toogle the div and show me another div with another table replacing the old one , as u can see "Document Editor" remains same in header only table changes.

[image: UI2]

consider the first UI as table 1 and second UI as table2 , so i am getting the data for table 2 by performing some queries on table 1 data ,
table 1 works fine and when performing queries with data obtained from table 1 is also getting printed on terminal , but when i send the data through return render , it is not getting printed in table 2.

So here is my code :

```
def secondtableonDashboard(request):
    Server_list = ""
    NewList = ""
    afterConcat = ""
    conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                          'Server=ABC\SQLEXPRESS;'
                          'Database=WebstartUI;'
                          'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("select * from CustomerServer")
    result = cursor.fetchall()

    if request.method=='POST': # ------> getting value from first table 
       user_list = request.POST.getlist('checked_list')
       Server_list = listToString(user_list) +","
    else:
       print("No Values")

    for listValue in Server_list.split(","):
        NewList = "'"+listValue+"',"
        afterConcat = afterConcat + NewList
    Server_list = afterConcat[:-5]
    Server_list = Server_list[1:]
    ServiceList = conn.cursor()
    cmd = "Select * from dbo.ServiceRunningStatus where ServerName IN ('"+Server_list+"')" #---> performing query 
    ServiceList.execute(cmd)
    resultOfServiceList = ServiceList.fetchall()
    print(resultOfServiceList) #---> result gets printed perfectly .

    return render(request,'side-menu-light-tabulator.html',{'customerserver':result,'ServerList':resultOfServiceList}) #-->
```

returning the result ...here customerserver is first table data and  and ServerList is second table data

html:

```
 {% for services in ServerList %}

  <td>{{services.ServerName}}</td>
  <td>{{services.Component}}</td>
  <td>{{services.PID}}</td>
   <td>{{services.State}}</td>
  {% endfor %}
```

but this data is not getting printed on second table and getting printed in network response preview. Can anyone help me to find the mistake i did

[image]

Comment: Are you sure of extending Block Content right ?

Comment: block content ? , am new to django and am not so sure about it .

Comment: in django template language you should put page content inside block content to be viewed
`
{% block content %}
<!---- Content Here --->
{% endblock content %}
`

Comment: but am not using base.html @omarahmed

Comment: no probem .... i mean in your template you should have {% block content %} to view page content ... add this tag first and inside add your code ... and don't forget to add templates directory path in settings file

Comment: i did but , no use . So i edited the code .... Can u check on this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/66865604/15219573    @omarahmed